# Double or triple gaps in grid in the media queries - the layout is not centered

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

The Problem in CSS Grid: Start with an odd number of cells and in media-queries to an even number. There will be an double gap in the media-queries and the layout isn't centered anymore.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 280px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 140px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "l-1 logo l-3";
  justify-content: center;
}

.l-1 {
  grid-area: l-1;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.l-3 {
  grid-area: l-3;
}

.logo-wrapper > div,
.content-wrapper > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, 240px) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 240px);
  gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: 
  " ol-1   c-1  c-2  c-3  or-3"
  " ol-5   c-4  c-5  c-5   c-5";
  justify-content: center;
}

.ol-1 {
  grid-area: ol-1;
}

.ol-2 {
  grid-area: ol-2;
}

.c-1 {
  grid-area: c-1;
}

.c-2 {
  grid-area: c-2;
}

.c-3 {
  grid-area: c-3;
}

.or-3 {
  grid-area: or-3;
}

.ol-5 {
  grid-area: ol-5;
}

.c-4 {
  grid-area: c-4;
}

.c-5 {
  grid-area: c-5;
}

.bgGrey {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.bgRed {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

.bgBeige {
  background-color: #e2d8cb;
}

.bgViolet {
  background-color: #ff4dff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 844px) {
  .logo-wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 250px 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 160px;
    grid-template-areas: ". logo logo .";
  }

  .content-wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, 240px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 240px);
    grid-template-areas:
       ". c-1  c-5 ."
       ". c-2  c-3 ."
       ". c-4  .   .";
    /* VERY VERY bad fiddle, this cannot be the right answer!
    grid-template-columns: 20px repeat(2, $blockSize);
    grid-template-areas:
    ". c-1  c-5"
    ". c-2  c-3"
    ". c-4  .  "; */
  }
  .ol-1 div {
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>from odd to even</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="l-1"></div>
    <div class="logo bgRed">Logo</div>
    <div class="l-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="ol-1">
      <div>ol-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-1 bgBeige">Home</div>
    <div class="c-2 bgGrey"></div>
    <div class="c-3 bgRed">Image1</div>
    <div class="or-3"></div>
    <!-- new column -->
    <div class="ol-5"></div>
    <div class="c-4 bgRed">Image2</div>
    <div class="c-5 bgViolet">Work</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a more complex example:

```
https://codepen.io/AndreasFoehl/pen/WwJMpW
```

In the large view everything is ok,
the magic starts in the css, media queries at column 219.

The upper Logo-Part is centered,
at 844px, the .content-wrapper isn't centered anymore.
Here is the grid-view in Firefox:

[image: lower part not centered]

I think I might have a problem understanding grid in the media queries.
What about the cells you omit.
Cells that aren't empty make problems. Is display: none enough for the content inside?

This is just an example, here is the full and more complicated template

```
http://wkm4.binart.de/arbeiten.html
```

Comment: Please give a fuller description of what you want to happen at different break points and in that include relevant code which we can run to see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that. Giving only links to external resources won't help future readers if those sources move.

Comment: In my original this one helped - but it cannot be the answer, it's such a bad fiddle, just putting an additional column in the size of the gap.

grid-template-columns: 20px repeat(2, $blockSize);
grid-template-areas:
    ". c-1  c-5"
    ". c-2  c-3"
    ". c-4  .  ";

Comment: Thanks for putting in more code but I'm afraid I'm still a bit confused about what you want as the final layouts. What are ol-1 and or-1 etc items for? Will they have content in them finally? At the moment they look as though they are there just for centering. Maybe a couple of pictures (a sketch will be fine) showing the two layouts you want would help.